# Hadoop: Incorrect configuration

Tags: macos, hadoop, osx-elcapitan

Hi stackoverflow community, 
so I've been wanting to install hadoop, but I have come to a problem. 
I've looked at other approaches, but I still keep receiving. I am completely new to hadoop, so I don't really know where to go. I am on a macbook pro with El Capitan if relevant. Once I make sbin/start-dfs.sh I receive this:

```
sbin/start-dfs.sh
16/05/10 11:09:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
Password:
localhost: /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 69: [: MacBook: integer expression expected
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/libexec/logs/hadoop-name-namenode-name’s
localhost: Error: Could not find or load main class MacBook
```

The hadoop-daemon.sh is:

[image]

The relevant XMLs are as follow:

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

If anything is wanted I will freely provide. Thank you for all the help and I truly appreciate it, since I really want to start using Hadoop.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop
```

Hey so this is an update if anyone is considered: I now get this

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [myIP@]
```

New note: I am redoing the process with and refollowing this guide. Whether or not success is mine, I will post my update here :)!

```
zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/…
```

Comment: If you just want to try Hadoop, then download a pre-built distribution from Cloudera or Hortonworks. (Called the Quickstart VM or Sandbox, respectively)

Comment: is there any way around the virtual box?

Comment: i just wanted to run it as an Eclipse plugin

Comment: Eclipse Plugin?? Hadoop is a framework. You are trying to configure the Hadoop binaries to talk to a cluster by editing those XML files. You'll need to install HDFS+YARN+Zookeeper at a minimum to "install Hadoop". The virtualbox simply bundles all that for you

Comment: I was previously attempting to do the plugin, but I gave up on that since the github repository's README.md was outdated. I apologize for not clarifying that. Also, for the virtual machine, is there no way around that and thank you for bearing through my ignorance. Lastly, I only ask since this Professor seemed to install an old version on Mac's OS without a virtual machine. http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs246-2011/hw_files/hadoop_install.pdf. I've been loosely been following this though: http://zhongyaonan.com/hadoop-tutorial/setting-up-hadoop-2-6-on-mac-osx-yosemite.html.

Comment: You could try starting the [MiniCluster](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CLIMiniCluster.html). I don't think configs are needed to start that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your conf directory is not set properly try following steps

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR = $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
hdfs namenode -format
hdfs getconf -namenodes
./start-dfs.sh
```

Comment: So I changed the dir hadoop like you said and receive this.

Comment: Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /etc/hadoop
Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /etc/hadoop
Starting secondary namenodes [2016-05-10 12:07:27,079 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(62)) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
0.0.0.0]
Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /etc/hadoop

Comment: Did you set HADOOP_HOME ?, try setting that to your installation dir

Comment: Yes: export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2

Comment: From the exception, it is looking at /etc/hadoop as the HADOOP_CONF_DIR, Try settings HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.2/etc/hadoop

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question, but would this be in the command line or in the actual hadoop-env.sh? Oh and I really appreciate the help!

Comment: It depends,  Every distribution has its own paths and they update evn file during installation.

Comment: Ok so these are the paths i currently have I'll post them above

Comment: Should I get rid of HADOOP_PREFIX, since isn't HADOOP_CONF_DIR  the same?

Comment: kk so i think I know what is going on. The path I am providing has not etc folder